# Двигаются блоки при наведении

Tags: html, css

Скажите пожалуйста почему у меня постоянно дергаются блоки которые расположены в одну строку один за другим?

```css
ul li{
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #464646;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.clear{
 clear: both;
}
.catalog{
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.catalog_item:hover{
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 cursor: pointer;
}
.catalog_item{
 height: 406px;
 width: 266px;
 float: left;
 border: 2px solid #6d87b4;
 margin: 50px 30px 0 0;
 position: relative;
}
.catalog_item>div{
 margin: 18px 0 0 23px;
}
.catalog_item>p{
 font: 20px RobotoBold;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    left: 23px;
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}
.catalog_item ul{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.catalog_item ul li{
 clear: both;
}
/*.catalog_item ul li:last-child a{
 opacity: 0.7;
}*/
.catalog_item ul li:hover a{
 color: #f7cac9;
}
.catalog_item ul li:before {
    content:  "—";
    position: relative;
    /*left: -5px;*/
    color: #6d87b4;
}
.catalog_item ul li a{
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.catalog_item div>a{
 text-decoration: underline;
    color: #6d87b4;
}
.catalog_item:nth-child(4n+4), .article:nth-child(4n+4), .factories a:nth-child(4n+4){
 margin-right: 0;
}
.catalog_item img{
  width:220px;
  height:180px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
 <div class="catalog_item">
  <p>Мебель для зала</p>
  <div>
   <img src="images/Img_2.png" alt""/>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Витрины</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Гостиные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Комоды</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Полки</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Столовые комплекты</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Столы журнальные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Столы обеденные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Стулья деревянные</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div> 
   <a href="">Показать все</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="catalog_item">
  <p>Детские</p>
  <div>
   <img src="images/Img_3.png" alt""/>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Диваны для детской</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Детские комнаты</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Детские матрасы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Комоды</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кресла</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кровати двухъярусные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кровати односпальные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кроватки для малышей</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div> 
   <a href="">Показать все</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="catalog_item">
  <p>Кухни</p>
  <div>
   <img src="images/Img_4.png" alt""/>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Кухонные углы и диваны</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Модульные кухни</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Основания для столов</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Столовые комплекты</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Столы обеденныек</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Столы деревянные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Стулья деревянные</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Стулья металлические</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div></div>
 <div class="catalog_item">
  <p>Мягкая мебель</p>
  <div>
   <img src="images/Img_5.png" alt""/>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Диваны в наличии</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Диваны прямые</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Диваны детские</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Диваны угловые</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Комплекты</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кухонные углы и диваны</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кресла</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Кресла-кровати</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div> 
   <a href="">Показать все</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

И как при наведении можно поменять цвет тире перед списком? Я пробовала так-

```
.catalog_item ul li:hover li:before{
    color: #f7cac9;
}
```

Comment: Ответ на второй вопрос такой: `.catalog_item ul li:hover:before`.

Comment: Вам не нужно выбирать `li` который вложен в `li:hover`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При ховере у вас стоит `border: none;`, чтобы блоки не двигались при наведении необходимо для `.catalog_item` прописать свойство `box-sizing: border-box;`

Для изменения цвета тире перед пунктами списка используйте селектор `.catalog_item:hover ul li:before`

UPD: Если предполагалось, что цвет тире меняется по наведению на пункт списка, как отметил в комментарии выше **Arnial**, используйте селектор `.catalog_item ul li:hover:before`.

Comment: либо сделать `border-color: transparent`

Comment: Полагаю цвет тирэ, должен изменяться при наведении на пункт меню внутри списка. А не при наведении на список.

Comment: Да, упустил этот момент, вы правы)

Comment: `border-box` не решит проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Сдвиг происходит из-за изменения размеров элемента при наведении - исчезает граница.

Правильнее всего это исправить установкой `border-color: transparent`.

Так же возможно заменить исчезновение border'а за счёт увеличения padding'а, но этот способ не только потребует больше усилий в плане реализации (надо посчитать, какой padding выставить, а ещё может оказаться, что единицы измерения у padding и border разные из-за чего понадобится calc), но и вызовет более существенные перерасчёты в браузере.

Вариант с изменением `box-sizing` на `border-box` не является решением. Да, снаружи блоки (в большинстве случаев, но не обязательно) шевелиться перестанут, но из-за изменения внутреннего размера блока, на который навели мышь, внутри него что-то начнёт двигаться.